# iOS universal deep-link not working when url start with "app."

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Universal deep linking not working with the url starting with "app." for e.g. below url

**app.xyz.com**

but when I changed above mentioned url to **earn.xyz.com**, it's working fine.

> How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: We have the exact same URL starting with app.xyz.com. Can you post examples where in the Xcode project you've configured the URLs?

Comment: @FlorianMielke I have edited my post